# How to add library project from lib folder without importing into workspace for android application?

Tags: android, facebook, android-library

I am implementing android application let say application A. I want to give facebook share feature for my application A. So i need to use Facebook SDK library. I need to add reference for facebook SDK library application to my application A. I want to place facebook SDK into "lib" folder. Is it possible to add library project to my application A from "lib" folder? Is it possible to link library project without importing into workspace in eclipse?

Comment: You need jar file of library to use in lib folder.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't have lib file. I have android library project. Which i can import into workspace and add to my project. But i don't want to import into workspace. I just want to add path to library project that should do the job.

Comment: eclipse in 2015 ? omg ... please you need a update, use Android studio, eclipse is deprecated. google do not support to eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

From properties Click Add External Class Folder and browse your library project files as I have entered facebook sdk library path. Then Build the project, This worked for me!

Comment: Tried the same but getting compilation errors at "import" statements in classes which are initializing facebook related classes. Checked the added facebook library in "Order and Export" also.

Comment: I am getting the following compilation error at the following lines in my activity files
"import com.facebook.FacebookException" unresolved import

Comment: remove all facebook related imports and then press ctrl+shift+o which will auto import everything.